# Как сделать оплату через сервис google play с помощью calabash-android?

Tags: android, test-automation, uiautomation

Тестирую на физических девайсах. Мне надо написать тест который совершает покупку vip аккаунта в приложении, с помощью фрейма google play. Но сам фрейм не отображается.

Для написания тестов использую calabash-android, ruby

`calabash-android console apk`

`start_test_server_in_background`

`query("*")`  = фрейм Google Play не отображается, его просто нет

`monitor` - по этой команде можно посмотреть id элементов, там фрейм отображается и кнопка `buy`  имеет уникальный id

Возможно кто-то уже решал подобную проблему. Как описать тест покупки?
Вариант клика по координатам пока не рассматриваю, т.к. для каждого девайса кнопка `buy` будет иметь другие координаты

Comment: А нельзя ли нажать на `buy` программно?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Мне и надо это сделать программно, как я и сказал я пишу авто-тесты. После запуска тестов я нахожусь в ` irb ` консоле, возможно можно использовать ` adb ` команду которая может тапнуть на кнопку ` buy `. На вопрос как это сделать? Я пока не нашел ответа и нахожусь в поиске.